# Race condition with CUDA shuffle?

Tags: cuda

Using the shuffle command, are there race conditions/lost updates when two different threads concurrently attempt to update the same register value?

Comment: Note sure I understand you question correctly. Seems that you mixing up register file and shared memory: registers are allocated statically to threads of a block. ie., each thread gets its own copy of registers, hence there is no race conditions by definition (btw, this is also the reason why context switch between warps is almost for free on the GPU). While shared memory can be accessed by threads of a block concurrently, therefore race conditions are possible if no barrier sync is used

Comment: asm, i am referring to a new command in cuda 5 called __shuffle(). Within a warp any thread can update a register value. Assuming that two threads x,y belonging to the same warp, attempting to update the value on register z at the same time, do we have race conditions/lost update?

Comment: aah gotcha, you are referring to shuffle intrinsics. This should happen "atomically" within a warp, ie. no race conditions can occur if, suppose, two threads in a warp refer to one another as source operands for update

Comment: Exactly that was what i was referring to...thanks for the answer as it came just in time i needed it...:)))

Comment: Although there is a little confusion here. The manual says that you can exchange values, but the way i get it is, that you can read the value of a register within a warp, but cannot alter its value...If i got it right, then there is no suspicion of race conditions there..

Comment: yes you can alter the values of registers, e.g.
x = __shfl_xor(x, 31, 32);
performs "butterfly" operation, ie. 
thread 0 gets thread's 31 'x' value; thread 1 gets thread's 30 'x' value, etc. up to thread 31 which gets thread's 0 'x' value. This is equivalent to the following: shared[threadIdx.x] = x; __syncthreads(); x = shared[(threadIdx.x & ~32) + ((threadIdx.x % 32) ^ 31)];

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer provided here to remove this question from the unanswered list.

From the CUDA C Programming Guide

> The `__shfl()` intrinsics permit exchanging of a variable between threads within
>   a warp without use of shared memory

The idea is that a thread `i` can read, but not alter, the value of a register `r` assigned to thread `j`. So, and as pointed out in the comments above, there is no race condition.

The CUDA C Programming Guide provides also the following example to broadcast of a single value across a warp

```
global__ void bcast(int arg) {

    int laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    int value;

    if (laneId == 0)          // Note unused variable for
    value = arg;              // all threads except lane 0
    value = __shfl(value, 0); // Get "value" from lane 0
    if (value != arg) printf("Thread %d failed.\n", threadIdx.x); }

void main() {
    bcast<<< 1, 32 >>>(1234);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

In this example, the value of the `value` register assigned to thread `0` in the warp is broadcast to all other threads in the warp and assigned to the local `value` registers. All the other threads **are not attempting** (**but also cannot**) **alter** the value of the `value` register assigned to thread `0`.